# Calling \usepackage{caption} overwrites Table name in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions

I am encountering strange problem with beamer and caption package. Namely when i use caption package for some settings along with beamer the table name is somehow overwritten with figure name:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            FIGURE
            \caption{My figure}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{table}
            TABLE
            \caption{My table}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Commenting out the caption package (last preamble line) brings things to the normal, but of course justification does not work anymore... Can someone point me out what is going no here?

Comment: I get  Table 1 not  Figure 2 with texlive 2019 and texlive 2020

Comment: First one note about chasing errors: get rid of everything you don't need to illustrate the issue. Regarding your question: I get the expected output! Figure is labeled "Figure 1" and the table is labeled "Table 1". I use the following setup TexLive 2019/Debian with LuaTex 1.10.0 and Beamer 2019/09/29.

Comment: Removing everything except caption line gives me the same wrong output... I use current Texlive 2019.51075-8 on Manjaro Linux, PDFLatex and Beamer 2019/09/29 v3.57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, as others also pointed out in their comments, your document produces a correct result (with TeXLive 2018, TeXLive 2019 and TeXLive 2020).

But as you suspect that the `caption` package is the cause of your bug, as a workaround, the following document produces the correct result without using this package. It defines and uses a new `caption` Beamer template named `centered and numbered caption w/o caption package` and contains very long captions.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\defbeamertemplate{caption}{centered and numbered caption w/o caption package}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \centering%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{caption name}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
      \insertcaptionname\space\insertcaptionnumber%
    }%
    \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}%
    \insertcaption%
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[centered and numbered caption w/o caption package]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \fbox{My figure}
    \caption{My figure with a very... very... very... very... very... very very very
      very very long caption}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{My table with a very very very very very very very very
             very very long caption}
    \fbox{My table}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Your solution just works and solves my problem. Thanks! However the question where is the problematic difference between our setups still remains...